# Automatizar deploy solución o proyecto c# en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, deployment

gracias por leer mi consulta.
Lo que estoy necesitando hacer y hasta ahora no pude encontrar la forma es compilar una solución (a veces puede ser un proyecto de esa solución) en C# en modo Release y ubicar en una carpeta remota de un servidor, solamente los archivos que se actualizaron con respecto a la última compilación.
Lo que hacemos ahora es compilar la solución o proyecto, tomar de la carpeta de salida de la compilación los archivos con las fechas más recientes (generalmente con la fecha del día) y copiarlos a una carpeta remota para que actualicen una aplicación web.
Hoy hay una serie de protocolos a seguir que son de varios pasos y a veces nos olvidamos copiar algún que otro archivo o cambiar de Debug a Release, y pedir que actualicen la aplicación con esos archivos. Lo ideal sería que, una vez copiados esos archivos, se genere un mail notificando a la sección que se encarga de actualizar la aplicación con los nuevos archivos compilados, sería genial.
Agradezco cualquier información o dato que me pueda guiar para lo que necesito.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: hay procesos automatizados y mil formas de hacer esto... todo depende donde tengan las cosas... inclusive todo se puede hacer automatico por git...

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, y cual sería alguna de esas formas ?, los archivos los tengo que poner en una carpeta determinada en un servidor Windows. Saludos